# How to use GitHub repository's md files(ex 100 files) content to be visible on a Website?

Tags: javascript, github, client, markdown, react-markdown

I am developing a project in which there will be some content. For example, a website having a list of technical articles.
I am planning to create a open source GitHub repo in which people can add articles in markdown files. Like, one article = one md file.

Ex Project -
Article list

User can click on an item and see the article content.

Can I do a fetch call to get the content of the article from the github repo?
Or is there any better approach to use GitHub's md files content in a website?

I want to make it dynamic, as if someone contribute to the GitHub repo, if should reflect in the website.

I want to use GitHub repo as DB of my website from which I can fetch the content. Will there be any performance issue?

A repo can have 500 articles/md files. Which i want to use it as a content in my website.

I am using react-markdown library to show the file content in the UI.

Any example or tutorial would be appreciated.

Thanks you

Comment: It sounds like you want a _static site generator_. I'd suggest doing some research about that.

Comment: My project has dynamic content currently, storing and fetching from firestore. But for future, I want something easy, in which I can format and add content in a single file. And use that. But through api calls.

Comment: Then maybe a CMS. But either way SO isn't here for recommendations or off-site resources; see the [help].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.